# how to manage opened windows between multiple monitors like I did in windows 10?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, 20.04, dock

I am a over 20 years windows user and come to linux recently. I would like to make ubuntu more like windows. so far so good, I move the dock to the bottom of the screen, which makes me right at home. now the only problem is that:
the docks(taskbars in windows 10) in each monitor always show exactly the same icons with the same status. what I really want is that, I have all the icons I pinned to dock(taskbar) to only show in the main monitor(my laptop builtin monitor), and then for the second monitor, to only show the icon of the opened windows(active only in current monitor).

Can you please tell me if it is possible in Ubuntu? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Xubuntu which uses a light weight XFCE desktop environment. It supports adding as many panels/taskbar as you wish.
I'll try adding a screen shot when I get to my PC.